Signing EXE with both SHA256 and SHA384 (and SHA1 ?) nowadays recommended?
My old build script has been saving multiple SHAs without problems for years.
Nowadays, when the cert is located on USB TOKEN, the signtool does not seem to store multiple SHAs on EXEs, even when these are both signed in the newer batch file (see below); the file appears to have only SHA384.
I would still like to make my installer exe compatible with older Win7 devices etc.
How can I make EXE that is compatible for as wide audience as possible, even if someone uses IExplorer?
MY OLD SCRIPT:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a %1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha1 /fd sha1 /a %1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha384 /fd sha384 /a %1

MY NEW SCRIPT (FOR TOKEN):
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a %1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha384 /fd sha384 /a %1


Use an older version of Windows Kit. SHA1 isn’t secure so I am pretty sure newer versions of supported versions of Windows does support it, support was removed years ago, and Windows 7 would be the only version that would support it and still have IE

I just realized your use the same version of the WDK.  What has changed on the system running the script? I do know Windows no longer will trust applications signed with SHA1. So that might be the problem regardless of the version of WDK your using
